# Perform multiple statements in one line in Python 3.2.3

Tags: python

Is there a way to execute multiple statemens while performing them in one line, like this:

```
import time
print ("Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now.")
time.sleep(0.5)
print (".") # This should print on the same line as the previous print statement.
time.sleep(0.5)
print (".") # ... As should this one
```

... So the output should be:

```
Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now.*.*.
```

*Waits .5 seconds

Comment: You can call sys.stdout.write(). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove.

Comment: As this is a purely python related question and can be better served in other SE site, (such as Stack Overflow), I see this as off-topic here.

Comment: Sorrt @KalleElmér, I'be jsut started learning Python about a month ago - could anyone give an expleanation on how to accomplish my example in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, the `print` statement automatically adds a line feed, so you need to use sys.stdout.write() instead. You will also have to import sys. The code you have written should look like this instead:

```
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now.")
time.sleep(0.5)
sys.stdout.write(".")
time.sleep(0.5)
sys.stdout.write(".")
```

In Python 3, `print` is a function accepting keyword arguments. You can use the `end` keyword argument to specify what should be placed after your string. By default it's a new line character, but you can change it to an empty string:

```
import time
print("Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now.", end='')
time.sleep(0.5)
print(".", end='')
time.sleep(0.5)
print(".", end='')
```

Also, remember that streams are buffered, so it's better if you flush them:

```
import time
import sys
print("Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now.", end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(0.5)
print(".", end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(0.5)
print(".", end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with the `end=""` syntax also.

```
print("this ",end="")
print("will continue on the same line")
print("but this wont")
```

Will return

```
this will continue on the same line
but this wont
```

so the following would work as well.

```
import time
print ("Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now.",end="")
time.sleep(0.5)
print (".",end="") # This should print on the same line as the previous print statement.
time.sleep(0.5)
print (".") # ... As should this one
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this simpler?:

```
import time
print ("Ok, I know how to write programs in Python now."),
time.sleep(0.5)
print ("."), # This should print on the same line as the previous print statement.
time.sleep(0.5)
print (".") # ... As should this one
```

Comment: This does not work in Python3

Comment: Oh, thanks! This is what happens when you don't update ;-)!

Comment: I don't think you should space you parentheses like that either ;), and you don't get an update from Python2.7 to 3.* - you have to install it with `$ su -`, `# apt-get install python3`, because Python2.7 is still used a lot. 12.10 should have switched though...

Answer (score 0):

Can this also be done with inputs?

```
print("THIS IS A TEST AREA")
print()
print("TETST OF SAME LINE INTERACTION")
print("X:  ", end="") #This works Fine
input("")
time.sleep(0.5)  #This however dew to python3 wont?
print("     STAR")
```

This output looks like so...

```
THIS IS A TEST AREA

TETST OF SAME LINE INTERATION
X:  
     STAR
>>>
```